# What is bash/zsh "|&" syntax mean?

Tags: bash, zsh

What is `|&` syntax means? For example:

```
tree |& less
```

I see no difference with `tree |& less`.

Comment: I see `|& was added to Bash 4 as an abbreviation for 2>&1 |` for bash. Is it the same for zsh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

```
command1 [ [| or |&] command2 …]
```

If `|&` is used, the standard error of `command1` is connected to `command2`’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`. This implicit redirection of the standard error is performed after any redirections specified by the command.

In [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Simple-Commands-_0026-Pipelines) too, `|&` is a shorthand for `2>&1 |`